# opening computer files using kivy, getting a unicode error

Tags: python, kivy, python-unicode

```
import kivy
 
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.filechooser import FileChooserListView
Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', '0')#keeps screen in a smaller window when running
Config.write() 
import os


class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
 
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyWidget,self).__init__(**kwargs)
 
        container = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
 
        filechooser = FileChooserListView()
        filechooser.bind(on_selection=lambda x: self.selected(filechooser.selection))
 
        open_btn = Button(text='open', size_hint=(1, .2))
        open_btn.bind(on_release=lambda x: self.open(filechooser.path, filechooser.selection))
 
        container.add_widget(filechooser)
        container.add_widget(open_btn)
        self.add_widget(container)
 
    def open(self, path, filename):
        print(filename)
        if len(filename) > 0:
            with open(os.path.join(path, filename[0])) as f:
                print(f.read())  
 
    def selected(self, filename):
        print("selected: %s" % filename[0])
  
 
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

[image: picture of the file im trying to open]

I am trying to create a program that can open files in kivy, I have a feeling its something to do with my 'os.path.join' I tried to add 'enconding =utf-8' to the area in the code where it says 'with open' that did not work in both cases. Below is the full error, maybe im missing something but hopefully the full error will help.

```
   UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-ad2b3c0779e3> in <module>
     45 
     46 if __name__ == '__main__':
---> 47     MyApp().run()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py in run(self)
    853 
    854         self.dispatch('on_start')
--> 855         runTouchApp()
    856         self.stop()
    857 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py in runTouchApp(widget, slave)
    502             _run_mainloop()
    503         else:
--> 504             EventLoop.window.mainloop()
    505     finally:
    506         stopTouchApp()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py in mainloop(self)
    745         while not EventLoop.quit and EventLoop.status == 'started':
    746             try:
--> 747                 self._mainloop()
    748             except BaseException as inst:
    749                 # use exception manager first

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py in _mainloop(self)
    477 
    478     def _mainloop(self):
--> 479         EventLoop.idle()
    480 
    481         # for android/iOS, we don't want to have any event nor executing our

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py in idle(self)
    340 
    341         # read and dispatch input from providers
--> 342         self.dispatch_input()
    343 
    344         # flush all the canvas operation

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py in dispatch_input(self)
    325         post_dispatch_input = self.post_dispatch_input
    326         while input_events:
--> 327             post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
    328 
    329     def idle(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py in post_dispatch_input(self, etype, me)
    291                         wid.dispatch('on_touch_up', me)
    292                 else:
--> 293                     wid.dispatch('on_touch_up', me)
    294 
    295             wid._context.pop()

kivy\_event.pyx in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py in on_touch_up(self, touch)
    177         else:
    178             self._do_release()
--> 179         self.dispatch('on_release')
    180         return True
    181 

kivy\_event.pyx in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch()

kivy\_event.pyx in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch()

kivy\_event.pyx in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch()

<ipython-input-1-ad2b3c0779e3> in <lambda>(x)
     23 
     24         open_btn = Button(text='open', size_hint=(1, .2))
---> 25         open_btn.bind(on_release=lambda x: self.open(filechooser.path, filechooser.selection))
     26 
     27         container.add_widget(filechooser)

<ipython-input-1-ad2b3c0779e3> in open(self, path, filename)
     33         if len(filename) > 0:
     34             with open(os.path.join(path, filename[0])) as f:
---> 35                 print(f.read())
     36 
     37     def selected(self, filename):

~\anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py in decode(self, input, final)
     21 class IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):
     22     def decode(self, input, final=False):
---> 23         return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
     24 
     25 class StreamWriter(Codec,codecs.StreamWriter):

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 57: character maps to <undefined>




​
```

Comment: can you post full error message and output?

Comment: full error above

Comment: If you are trying to open that png file, you may need to specify a different decoder, or read it as bytes, or use a library to handle image files

Comment: The default for `open()` is to open the file  as a text file. Perhaps that is the problem.

Comment: ahh okay thanks, ill do some research into this